# Determining when a SSIS 2008 package was deployed on a server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I want to find when an SSIS 2008 package was deployed under MSDB in an instance of SQL Server. In the table `dbo.sysssispackages`, I can see package creation date but where can I find the last modified/deployed date of a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date an SSIS package was deployed to the MSDB is not tracked so you do not have the ability to know when a package was deployed, who performed this feat, etc.

With SQL Server 2012+ and the project deployment model, the SSISDB supports the ability to track when a project was deployed and by whom.

The best answer I have for you is much the same as Tab has just posted except I tied mine to VerBuild, which is a monotonically increasing number that VS updates whenever you save a package.

If it's absolutely crucial that you have this information, you could look at modifying `msdb.dbo.sp_ssis_putpackage`. That's definitely off the reservation so buyer beware, etc but depending on your appetite for risk, you could either extend dbo.sysssispackages by adding your custom columns there or create a new table dbo.sysssispackages_extended and there record who did what and when.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not stored, and is not available for retrieval from SQL Server.

The best way to make this information available that I have found is to use the Version-related fields (VersionMajor, VersionMinor, VersionComments) in the SSIS package.   Combined with use of source control, you can see which version of your package is currently live on your server, and find that version in source control to find which version of the code it is.